# Rebuilding array structure in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to change the structure of the array so I can add it to apexcharts.

**The original array structure:**

```
{
  "BANANA": [{
    "x": "01 Jan",
    "y": 1
  }],
  "APPLE": [{
    "x": "02 Jan",
    "y": 1
  }, {
    "x": "03 Jan",
    "y": 1
  }],
  "MANGO": [{
    "x": "04 Jan",
    "y": 1
  }]
}
```

**The structure I need:**

```
{
  "AnalyticData": [{
    "name": "BANANA",
    "data": [{
      "x": "01 Jan",
      "y": 1
    }, {
      "x": "02 Jan",
      "y": 0
    }, {
      "x": "03 Jan",
      "y": 0
    }, {
      "x": "04 Jan",
      "y": 0
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "APPLE",
    "data": [{
      "x": "01 Jan",
      "y": 0
    }, {
      "x": "02 Jan",
      "y": 1
    }, {
      "x": "03 Jan",
      "y": 1
    }, {
      "x": "04 Jan",
      "y": 0
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "MANGO",
    "data": [{
      "x": "01 Jan",
      "y": 0
    }, {
      "x": "02 Jan",
      "y": 0
    }, {
      "x": "03 Jan",
      "y": 0
    }, {
      "x": "04 Jan",
      "y": 1
    }]
  }]
}
```

**I tried with this php code:**

```
foreach ($DataArray as $Data => $Subchild)
{
   $parentDate[] = $Data;
   $AnalyticData[] = $Subchild;

   foreach (array_combine($parentDate, $AnalyticData) as $ChildName => $ChildData)
   {
      $resultData[] = array(
         'name' => $ChildName,
         'data' => $ChildData
      );
   }

}

$UniqueDataAnalytic = array_values(array_unique($resultData, SORT_REGULAR));
$JsonData = array(
   'AnalyticData' => $UniqueDataAnalytic
);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($JsonData);
```

**The output from this code is:**

```
{
  "AnalyticData": [{
    "name": "BANANA",
    "data": [{
      "x": "01 Jan",
      "y": 1
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "APPLE",
    "data": [{
      "x": "02 Jan",
      "y": 1
    }, {
      "x": "03 Jan",
      "y": 1
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "MANGO",
    "data": [{
      "x": "04 Jan",
      "y": 1
    }]
  }]
}
```

This output gives errors on apexcharts because it is missing the data where the `y` value is `0`, but apexcharts requires complete date data for each series.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to start by getting all the unique `x` values from the elements, to create a template `data` value for each item. Then you can go through the data again, replacing values in this template with the actual values.

Making this template an associative array keyed by the dates will make updating it easier. You can remove the keys with `array_values()` when you put it into the final result.

```
<?php

$DataArray = json_decode('
{
  "BANANA": [{
    "x": "01 Jan",
    "y": 1
  }],
  "APPLE": [{
    "x": "02 Jan",
    "y": 1
  }, {
    "x": "03 Jan",
    "y": 1
  }],
  "MANGO": [{
    "x": "04 Jan",
    "y": 1
  }]
}', true);

$template = [];
foreach ($DataArray as $val) {
    foreach ($val as $item) {
        $template[$item['x']] = ['x' => $item['x'], 'y' => 0];
    }
}
ksort($template);

$AnalyticData = [];
foreach ($DataArray As $key => $val) {
    $data = $template;
    foreach ($val as $item) {
        $data[$item['x']]['y'] = $item['y'];
    }
    $AnalyticData[] = [
        "name" => $key,
        "data" => array_values($data)
    ];
}

$JsonData = ['AnalyticData' => $AnalyticData];
echo json_encode($JsonData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: I tried to make something _better_, but I can only make something _different_ (worse/uglier/less-efficient). https://3v4l.org/8Assp  Outside of the vague variable names (`$key`, `$val`, `$item`; I'd prefer something like `$name`, `$rows`, `$row`), this answer looks rather perfect to me.

Comment: Oh, and I'd probably use `$defaults` instead of `$template` (again, totally a subjective preference).  Since `$item` is never used wholly, this is a good case to use destructing to produce single variables: `foreach ($val as ['x' => $x, 'y' => $y]) {`

Comment: @mickmackusa Despite using it all the time in python, I've never gotten into the habit of using destructuring like that in PHP.